# Combining two #defined symbols in C++ preprocessor

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I want to do:

```
#define VERSION XY123
#define PRODUCT MyApplication_VERSION
```

so that PRODUCT is actually MyApplication_XY123. I have tried playing with the merge operator ## but with limited success...

```
#define VERSION XY123
#define PRODUCT MyApplication_##VERSION
```

=> MyApplication_VERSION

```
#define VERSION XY123
#define PRODUCT MyApplication_##(VERSION)
```

=> MyApplication_(XY123) - close but not quite

Is what I want possible?

Comment: Try an intermidate macro. [This works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=9a58cc40bae07274adc03c34d119b2ce-2dd64d7c3463c0130a5007ce3cc40567), but you can probably cut it down. I don't play around with macros enough to remember how to do this properly.

Comment: Can you define version as `"XY123"`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Token pasting works with arguments to macros.  So try this

```
#define VERSION XY123
#define PASTE(x) MyApplication_ ## x
#define PRODUCT PASTE(VERSION)
```

Answer (score 8):

The `##` operator acts *before* argument substitution has taken
place.  The classical solution is to use a helper:

```
#define CONCAT2(a, b) a ## b
#define CONCAT(a, b) CONCAT2(a, b)

CONCAT(MyApplication_, VERSION)
```

Answer (score 2):

All problems in computer science can be solved by an extra level of indirection:

```
#define JOIN_(X,Y) X##Y
#define JOIN(X,Y) JOIN_(X,Y)
#define VERSION XY123
#define PRODUCT JOIN(MyApplication_,VERSION)
```

Comment: @MikeSeymour until you overflow the number of levels of indirection, and it goes to 0.