# C/C++ preprocessor - combined replace

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have different version of a base function `void *_function()`: `void *_function_standard()`, `*_function_secure()`, `*_function_fast()` 
and I want to define MACROS interfaces to be able to chose what function to call and what operations to do on the return value, for example casting, calling `FUNCTION_TYPE_MODE()`, without define each options redundantly.

What I'm trying to avoid:

```
#define F_CHAR           (unsigned char *)        _function_standard()
#define F_CHAR_FAST      (unsigned char *)        _function_fast()
#define F_CHAR_SECURE    (unsigned char *)        _function_secure()
#define F_SCHAR          (signed char *)          _function_standard()
#define F_SCHAR_FAST     (signed char *)          _function_fast()
#define F_SCHAR_SECURE   (signed char *)          _function_secure()
#define F_CHARPNT        (unsigned char **)       _function_standard()
#define F_CHARPNT_FAST   (unsigned char **)       _function_fast()
#define F_CHARPNT_SECURE (unsigned char **)       _function_secure()
#define F_SHORT          (unsigned short int *)   _function_standard()
#define F_SHORT_FAST     (unsigned short int *)   _function_fast()
#define F_SHORT_SECURE   (unsigned short int *)   _function_secure()
#define F_INT            (unsigned int *)         _function_standard()
#define F_INT_FAST       (unsigned int *)         _function_fast()
#define F_INT_SECURE     (unsigned int *)         _function_secure()
```

This can be a problem if I have to handle a lots of different types of data and more than 2/3 modalities (STANDARD, SECURE, FAST).

Instead what I need is to define MACROS the let me call a the function in FUNCTION_TYPE_MODE, defining only once the corrisponeces _FAST -> _function_fast(), _SECURE -> _function_secure() and between types.

```
F_SHORT()       -> (unsigned short int *)  _function_standard()
F_SHORT_FAST()  -> (unsigned short int *)  _function_fast()
F_CHAR_SECURE() -> (unsigned char *)       _function_secure()
...
```

And I want to define `DEFAULT_TYPE` and `DEFAULT_MODE`, so I can call `F()` for 
`(DEFAULT TYPE) _function/?fast()`.

I read : [Combining two #defined symbols in C++ preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591642/combining-two-defined-symbols-in-c-preprocessor), but I haven't understood yet how to do it with `FUNC_TYPE_MODE` form instead of the `FUNC(TYPE, MODE)` one.

Suggestions? :-)

Comment: Note: Names starting with two underscores are reserved for the implementation. Do not use them in user code! And your question is not clear. Sure you know yourself what you want to do? What is your **actual** problem?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. If you pick **one** of them, there might be a better solution.

Comment: You can create new tokens by pasting tokens together with `##` in macros, but you cannot dissect macro names. In other words, there is no way to get at the `SHORT` part in `F_SHORT` via the preprocessor. (And `F_CHAR*_FAST` isn't a valid macro name anyway.)

Comment: Why are you defining macros that cast the return value of a function?  This sounds like a pretty horrible thing to do in almost all cases.  Particularly given that you're casting the return value of the *same*  function to either a `short int *` or a `char **`.  Unless this is an exercise in learning the pre-processor, you're setting yourself up for disaster.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland I cast the return of the function because it's a void* pointer. My function is a function that can handle different type of data and the MACROS, yeah are an exercise in learning the preprocessor... Instead of calling the function, passing it the var type as an argument, I'm trying to keep it more generic as I can, providind higher level interfaces to use.

Comment: A `void*` does not need to be cast to assign to a pointer of a different type. e.g. `int x = malloc(sizeof(int));` is the normal / preferred pattern, NOT `int x = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));`

Comment: @Olaf Are there any differences related to this specific case?

Comment: Once you know both languages good enough you will see. Any way, this looks like a horrible approach. As @BrianMcFarland wrote: There is not even need to use macros. Problem with oyur function is how the caller and the function are supposed to know which type to return.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland  If you want to retrieve data from an array from a void* pointer and evaluate it you have to cast the pointer to the buffer var type: unsigned short int popped = *((unsigned short int *) __pop_function_modx()) or I can use memcpy, since I know the size of the buffer var type, however this is for learning purpose.

Comment: @NicholasRoveda: That does not contradict what brian wrote. The cast is not necessary because of the assignment, but because you cannot dereference `void *`. Different things! General rules for casts: Use cast if**f** 1) They are necessary **and** 2) you know about **all** implications **and** 3) **fully** accept them.

Comment: @Olaf It's for clarity: instead of write `FUNCTION(TYPE, MODALITY)` that is preprocessed as `(TYPE *) _function_MODALITY`, I'd want to use `FUNCTION_TYPE_MODE ` that seem beetter to me, cause you can see the function immediately in the code, for example `POP_INT(&stack)`, `POP_SHORT_SECURE(&stack)` instead of `POP(&stack, sizeof(int), FLAG_SECURE)`.

Comment: @NicholasRoveda: No, it just obfuscates your code, complicates debugging (yes, "real programmers **do** debug"!) and is not much less to type (unless you further obfuscates the names). Easiest way is to forget about the macros completely. Also note that you cannot comclude from `sizeof(xy)` to xy.

Comment: @Olaf Yeah, in this case it's not necessary, but as I wrote, it's for learning purpose, I want to discover the preprocessor and the `FUNCTION_TYPE_MODE` seeemed to me a good interface.

Comment: Well, you are wrong. Maybe in 10 years you will agree.

Comment: @Olaf Ok, I can agree with u rigth know, the point is that once I understand that there's a better way to achive what I proposed as an exaple for the real need, the real question is still there. I see what u meant in your comment, I appreciate it and it can help me to write better and cleaner code. Now u can tell me if what I'm trying to do is possible or not with the preprocessor?

Comment: I agree with @MOehm s comment.